# Speed up Banshee's indexing of files on a device

Tags: banshee

I've got an external hard drive with music on it, around 250 albums.  To make it work nicely with Banshee, I've created an `.is_audio_player` file on the device, containing `audio_folders=Music`.

Every time I plug it in, Banshee takes around two minutes to index the thing, slowly building up the library - and being unusably sluggish while doing that.

Is there, per chance, any way to speed it up? Should I not mount the hard disk as a music player, but add it's contents to my library? And, if I do, won't that give me lots of annoying <kbd>X</kbd> symbols next to the titles, as they can't be found sometimes?

What's the best way to have my library on an external HDD?

Comment: looks like no ones interested in answering any questions about Banshee at the mo Stefano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there, per chance, any way to speed it up?

I don't think so. When banshee scans the library, it reads the metadata of all files. This is a slow process, more if it has to scan ~250 albums (eq to 1300 song more or less). Another factor is the speed of the external hard drive and how it is plugged into the PC.

> Should I not mount the hard disk as a music player, but add it's contents to my library?

If you do so, and you add it's content to banshee, you will get (as you said yourself) a lot of error messages pointing that the media files could not be found. This is if you open banshee with the external hard drive disconnected.

> What's the best way to have my library on an external hard drive?

Summarizing, there is no better way other than having a local copy of your library (which would use ~7 GB).

Comment: It's more in the region of 200 gigabytes, around 5000 songs.

Comment: @stefano-palazzo: With more reason. Reading 200 GB in 2 minutes isn't slow at all